# How to remove seconds and microseconds from a timedelta?

Tags: python, date, python-datetime

I want to print the time delta between 2 dates without seconds or nanoseconds. I would also like to be able to extract just the day or just the month. Is this possible?

This is the code I have so far for this:

```
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 00)
t2 = datetime.datetime.today()

delta = t1 - t2

print(delta)
```

Comment: The amout of month ? What are the exact expceted outputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get without seconds nor microseconds, use slice the string version

```
from datetime import datetime
delta = datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 00) - datetime.now()

print(delta)             # 15 days, 11:24:04.767145
print(str(delta)[:-10])  # 15 days, 11:24
```

---

To get the days (or month) use `days` property

```
from datetime import datetime
delta = datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 00) - datetime.now()

print(delta.days)       # 15
print(delta.days / 30)  # 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `days` property to get the number of days in a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 00)
t2 = datetime.datetime.today()

delta = t1 - t2

print(delta.days)
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://replit.com/@esqew/ConventionalEvenRouter#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

you can use mod on the timestamp to round it to anything you want.

```
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 00)
t2 = datetime.datetime.today()
t2s = t2.timestamp()
# mod 60 removes seconds and fractions, mod 1 would just remove fractions of second, etc
t2s = t2s - t2s % 60
t2new = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t2s)

print(t2new)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore `second`/`microsecond` in the original `datetime`s, use [the `replace` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to set them to `0`, then perform the calculation:

```
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 00)  # Already lacks seconds
t2 = datetime.datetime.today().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)  # Gets datetime without second/microsecond data

delta = t1 - t2

print(delta)
```

You can't extract the months from a `timedelta` (because it has no granularity beyond days; a month or year has no fixed length after all), but the `.days` attribute of a `timedelta` will tell you how many complete days it represents.

I've omitted truncating data from the `timedelta` itself, as the other answers have that covered adequately (and in practice, I've found most people want, or can tolerate, the truncation being performed on the inputs, not the result).